# Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException : React Native iOS

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

The issue is happening in a React Native iOS project and is causing App Crashes.

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
UIViewController is missing its initial trait collection populated during initialization. This is a serious bug, likely caused by accessing properties or methods on the view controller before calling a UIViewController initializer. View controller: <CTAlertViewController: 0x107248cb0>
```

And its not specific to a screen, Crashes occur randomly.

Any suggestions or responses is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide more info like, Are you using UITableViewController or what is the type of your view controller?

Comment: Also, you said the error is not specific to the screen. But in your error message, it has given the view controller name which is causing the issue. Are you facing the same issue with your other view controllers?

Comment: It was a package issue, Upgraded the package and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If, Anyone else is getting this issue in a React Naive app, It's Probably because of a package you're using. Search for that specific View Controller in XCode which will reveal your culprit. Try updating the package to latest version.